# Turn text into a picture when it is a link with reactor

Tags: javascript, reactjs, linked-data

I'm building an linked data application and having some trouble with my code which is as following

```
import React from 'react';
import URIUtil from '../../../utils/URIUtil';
class BasicIndividualView extends React.Component {
render() {
    let val, outputDIV;
    val = this.props.spec.value;
    if(this.props.spec.valueType === 'uri'){
        if(this.props.config){
            if(this.props.config.truncateURI){
                val = '<' + URIUtil.truncateMiddle(val, 50, '') + '>';
            }else if (this.props.config.shortenURI) {
                val = '<' + URIUtil.getURILabel(val) + '>';
            }
        }
        outputDIV = <a href={this.props.spec.value} target="_blank"> {val} </a>;
    }else{
        outputDIV = <span> {val} </span>;
    }
    return (
        <div className="ui" ref="basicIndividualView">
            {outputDIV}
        </div>
    );
  }
}

export default BasicIndividualView;
```

Now I want to display text, and if the text is a link I want to show the picture.

Comment: Code looks fine. What's the output? You sure about the `if (this.props.spec.valueType === 'uri')` returns true?

Comment: It is all working en there are no errors, The only thing is when de database query comes up with a link of a picture it remains a link where I want it to be the picture itself

Comment: Ah, then it should look like `<a href={this.props.spec.value} target="_blank"><img src={this.props.spec.value}/></a>`

Comment: Yeah it should work like that but the problem is the link comes up as plain text, so even with de src property there is no change. Thanks anyway for your quick answer!